# Multiple Non-linear Regression with Function-based regression and Machine Learning models

Tags: regression, machine-learning, python, nonlinear-regression

I'm working on an application of ***Multi-nonlinear regression***. Initially, I tried this algorithmically by creating a polynomial of the form `A(x^p * y^q * z^r)`.  I saw poor results (highest ***r-squared value = 0.51***), as shown below.

FORMAT: `Output(x,y) = A*(1^2) + B*(1^1 * x^1) + C*(1^1 * y^1) + D*(x^2) + E*(x^1*y^1) + F*(y^2)`

Notice: The powers of the variables always add up to `2`.

[image: Algorithmic regression]

> Machine Learning

Seeing poor results here, I turned to machine learning applications. This produced only 70% accuracy (see below).

- Here's the code:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(128, input_dim=2, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(.2))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
np.random.seed(3)
saveModel = ModelPerformancePlot("D:\\models\\model_{epoch:02d}.hdf5", 
            input_test, output_test, monitor='val_loss', verbose=0, save_best_only=False, save_weights_only=False, mode='auto', period=1)
model.fit(input_train, output_train, validation_split = 0.50, epochs=256, 
          batch_size=64, verbose=2, callbacks = [saveModel])
```

- Here's the visual performance:

I understand *accuracy* isn't a good indicator of regression, I just added it to the graphic for visual effects.

[image: Machine Learning regression]

My **question**:

Is there a way of improving the Machine Learning algorithm to fit better?  Any suggestions on which layers are best for ***multi-nonlinear regression***?  What other options are there to ***Sequential.compile()***'s *metrics* parameter?  I do not want to use *accuracy*.  The documentation is unclear here.

Comment: Try adding a constant term "+ c" to the original regression, that should help.

Comment: @James Phillips Thanks for your comment.  I actually already have a "+ C".  I've updated the post to show the regression format better.  I've been chewing on an idea: breaking up the daily equation into three parts. If you look at the top graph, there is an exponential rise at the start of the day, a polynomial fit in the middle, and an exponential decrease at the end of the day.  Do you think it's possible to split regression like that?  Interesting stuff...

Comment: If you do this, i recommend some small data overlap between the differently modeled regions. This should help ensure smoother transitions between sections than if this were not done.

Comment: Thank you for zunzun.com, BTW.  I used it a few weeks ago and it was really cool. Although, I didn’t get the same results when implementing the fit polynomials in Python.

Comment: You are too kind, Oh Bearded One.